# Is there a way in Angular i18n/ngPluralize to retrieve the plural category of a number?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, locale, angularjs-ng-pluralize, angular-i18n

Given an expression or variable that returns a number, is there a way to get the plural category of that number for the current locale?

Something like

```
// people.length == 1
ngPluralize.getCategory(people.length) // returns 'one'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$locale` has [rather tiny public API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale). However, [there is a `$locale.pluralCat` method](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/angular-locale_en-gb.js#L141), so you can use it.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('LocaleCtrl', function($scope, $locale) {
    $scope.locale = $locale.id;
    $scope.getCategory = function(count) {
      return $locale.pluralCat(count);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.5/angular-locale_pl-pl.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="LocaleCtrl">
    <h1>ng-pluralize category for locale {{ locale }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="count in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
        category for {{count}} is {{ getCategory(count) }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, the results are different if you use [different locales](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/angular-locale_pl-pl.js#L141).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.